# What makes e2fsck -cc so slow?

Tags: hard-drive, raid, lvm, raid-0, fsck

This isn't a complaint or a request for tech support or help! I'm just curious about what's going on behind the scenes :)

I'm doing e2fsck -cc to flag bad blocks on an 8TB LVM ext4 filesystem. Currently it's about 45 minutes in with about 0.45% complete. It's 8TB, so it makes sense that it's gonna take a LONG time, which is fine - I understand it's a big job!

But it made me curious about the speed it was *actually* going, not just percentage wise. Plugging those numbers into a back of the envelope equation gets me around 12MB/s (95Mbps). That's well within the ballpark of a healthy read speed for my older, mechanical drives, so I feel like it's accurate. But it's definitely on the low end, so I'm wondering what is happening behind the scenes to result in that speed?

It's a non-destructive read-write test, so obviously it's going to be slower than just a read test, or even a destructive read-write test, but write speeds on these drives can generally get up to 100MB/s, and this LVM is striped across 2 drives (who live in a USB3.0 hub) with 64KB stripes, so theoretically there could also be load balancing happening too.

My understanding is that e2fsck -cc invokes badblocks -nsv (non destructive read-write), which from what I can tell essentially:

- Makes a backup of the data in a sector (the non-destructive part):

  - Reads the data first
  - Writes a backup
- Does the test:

  - Writes some test data to that sector
  - Reads the sector back to check if it wrote correctly.
- Cleanup?:

  - Erases the backup?
  - Erases the test data?

This makes sense. For every sector it tests, it has to read, write, write, read, then write (erase) again. Obviously the CPU is also doing a little work, but I don't think that's relevant in terms of speed? If we assume reads are twice as fast as writes (a big oversimplification), 3 or 4 writes + 2 reads gets us to 48-60MB/s. Much more reasonable, but still a little on the low side? Even if reads are are as fast as writes, that still gets up to about 84-96MB/s, which considering it's RAID0 still feels a little slow?

Can anyone confirm if my maths is broadly correct or let me know if I've made any mistakes?

Also bonus points if you can let me know ways I could potentially speed this up! And especially if you could provide some context for load balancing this operation, whether it's relevant or even possible or not, and how to take advantage of it if it is. It's freshly formatted so I don't really mind about doing a destructive test or cleaning the data up, so if there's a way to get e2fsck to do a destructive write test, we could potentially gain some speed?

Or any other info is great as well! I'm mostly just looking to learn and expand my brain :)